# Syntax for defining a "class constructor" in Java Script

Tags: javascript

Which syntax should I use when creating a "class constructor" in java script?

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

Or

```
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};
```

Comment: Try `class Person { constructor(name) { this.name = name; } }` instead

Comment: Do note that using the `class` declaration is only available for ES6 compliant environments.